# How do I set the default table type as innodb in my.cnf?

Tags: mysql, database, innodb

For mysql...is there a way to set it so that every table that gets created is innodb?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Edit your my.cnf file to set following in the [mysqld] section (or the section your MySQLd reads):

```
default-storage-engine=InnoDB
```

After restarting the MySQL server, InnoDB should be the new default. To verify this, run the SQL statement:

```
SHOW ENGINES;
```

...The InnoDB line should be indicated as DEFAULT.

Note that the **default-storage-engine** option is just an alternate name for **default-table-type**.

Comment: @lockie i couldnt find my.cnf file http://img691.imageshack.us/img691/524/mysqln.jpg plz help me...

Comment: Thanks, for me, needed to set default-storage-engine=InnoDB in WAMP > mysql > my.ini

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can

> default-storage-engine=InnoDB
>
> default-table-type=InnoDB

Comment: `default-table-type` is a deprecated synonym for `default-storage-engine`, and may cause MySQL to not start on 5.x. See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_default-table-type)

Answer (score 0):

I want to my Clustered Node to work like when I create a new database It won't get replicated. Normally after having the above mentioned attribute set 'default-storage-engine=INNODB', When I create a table without mentioning the engine it is not replicated to the other node, that is fine. But Why does the database gets created on other nodes?